# Bootstrap datetimepicker automatically populates date

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on datetimepicker current date automatically gets populated in input field. I want that it should populate only when I select a date in popup box. Is there any flag to do it ?

```
$('#datetimepickerStartDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD-MMM-YYYY'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I got the solution. It can be done by setting "useCurrent" to false.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `useCurrent` option to `false` will disable this functionality:

```
$('#datetimepickerStartDate').datetimepicker({
      useCurrent: false
   });
```